# dynamically created controls within a usercontrol is not recognized

Tags: asp.net

In the ascx.cs file I'm dynamically generating buttons. In .aspx file I add the control to the form. The control itself renders well, but when the buttons are clicked I get this error

> An error has occurred because a control with id 'ctl03' could not be
>   located or a different control is assigned to the same ID after
>   postback.

DestopControl.ascx.cs

```
public partial class DesktopControl : PlaceHolder
{

    public void Build()
    {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Button button = new Button()
        {
            Width = 50,
            Height = 50,
            ID = string.Format("button{0}", i),
            Text = i.ToString()
        };
        button.Click+=new EventHandler(button_Click);
    }
    }
}
```

Default.aspx.cs

```
DesktopControl desktop = new DesktopControl();
desktop.Build();
MainContent.Controls.Add(desktop);
```

Comment: Do you have your Default.aspx code (as shown above) inside an `if (!isPostBack){}`? if so, take it out of there.

Comment: Also - what is `ctl03` - this does not appear to be one of the ID's your setting in your code - they would be `button1` etc

Comment: Everything in my project is dynamically created controls. The first time in Page_Load event, If(!isPostBack) { ShowLoginPage(); } else { ReloadUI(Session["ui"]); }.
Basically, I make a call to a wcf service which returns UI definitions. I generate the controls based on the definitions and form1.Controls.Add(control).
After login, the WCF sends 'desktop' as ui, and I instantiate this 'DesktopControl' and add it to form1.Controls.Add(desktop). But the login UI stays there. I don't know how to clear the screen before rendering the new UI.

Comment: So, after login, I see both 'Login' control and 'Desktop' control when I only want to see 'Desktop' control. At this point I hit any button either in 'Login' control or 'Desktop' control I get the error as mentioned in my post.

The control name 'ctlxx' confuses me too, I'm not naming them 'ctlxx', somehow it's picking this name from no where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution:

Every time there is a new UI I call this ClearScreen() which does the trick.
The error on 'ctl03' was a menu control which was generating it's own ID and somehow wasn't available on postback. I assigned an ID to it. But I guess all the issue went away with this ClearScreen() method.

```
private void ClearScreen()
{
    try
    {
        List<Control> controls = new List<Control>();
        foreach (Control control in MainContent.Controls)
        {
            controls.Add(control);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < controls.Count; i++)
        {
            if (!(controls[i].GetType() == typeof(LiteralControl) || controls[i].GetType() == typeof(ScriptManager)))
            {
                MainContent.Controls.Remove(controls[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After reading the comments (little hard to read the code-part of the comments) it appears that yes, you are generating your controls inside an `if(!isPostBack){}`; well, looks like it's in the `else` part of that `if` statement.

You have to generate your controls every time the page posts back, as the `page_load` gets fired before your `button` click. So once the controls have been re-created the code will continue on to your `button` click handler, where the controls should be available to handle.

Essentially, take `ReloadUI(Session["ui"]);` OUT of the `if(!isPostBack){}else{}` statement. Put it after your `if` statement.

Like this:

```
if (!isPostBack){

    // my first load code
}else{
   // my postback code
}

// load all my dynamic controls here
ReloadUI(Session["ui"]);
```

Comment: I did that but still it's the same. I added a screenshot to my original post. You can see that the login control still stays there, it's supposed to be cleared and the new UI should be rendered. This model is originally built for silverlight where it works fine. I need to reproduce it in asp.net.

Comment: Don't think I can help anymore.. there must be far more code than you have shown, something is interfering. You need to find out what is getting set to ctl03 - perhaps look in the HTML source for that ID.

Comment: I found a solution and answered my own question.